# Codecademy or Khan Academy - Create a Classroom or Friends list?

Tags: khan-academy

I'm sorry if this is the wrong community, but Academia (my next-best-guess) seemed too focused on graduate-level stuff for something this trivial.

I have several friends who have expressed interest in learning to program.  I have referred them all to Codecademy (though upon review Khan Academy appears as *least* as good, possibly better).

The problem is, I am having trouble tracking their progress.  They tell me what question of what lesson they are on and I have to find it, or get into screen sharing.

**Is there a way for me to "connect" with these friends so they can share their progress with me?**

A "virtual classroom" or friends list would be great.  And I don't have any trouble moving them to a new platform (if it's any good) since I'd just doing this to help some people out.  This is not paid at all, so I'm not looking for a paid solution.

Anyone know how I can do this connection?  I know Duolingo has friends list, but German and PHP aren't quite the same kinds of languages.

Comment: Wouldn't this question be more appropriate for either site's support team?

Comment: I was open to other alternatives than just these two, but it appears CS educational resources isn't wanted in stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my answer (despite the lack of support here) and wanted to share, just in case anyone else thinks of asking StackOverflow, even if it's not really welcome here.

Khan Academy has a "coaching" program which allows you to create classrooms and assign classes accordingly.  If you have a wide range of students, you may need 1 student per classroom, but it can still work.  Codecademy lacks this as far as I can tell today, and the inquiry I already have out to them has not been returned yet.

Here is Khan Academy's coaching program:
https://www.khanacademy.org/coach-res

Answer (score 1):

At Codecademy there isn't a "friends" feature. For teachers, there is Pupil Tracking.

http://www.codecademy.com/schools/curriculum